# Validate one of two forms

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I was able to use vuelidate very well to validate my forms.
Now I have two tabs and in one tab a form to login and on another tab a
form to register. I have to validate only one of two forms.

When I switch to the login form, the form should be only login form 
validation conditions should be checked.

If I switched to sign up form, and press submit button.
Only the sign up form should be validated.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late, but maybe it may help someone. I think the easier way to do it, is splitting each tab up in a different component and in each one you use vuelidate as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late but I just ran into the same issue and I just figured it out and I thought I would share.

I also have a Login/Sign Up form that is two tabs on the same component. If you split the validation based on how your forms are split like this:

```
validations: {
  login: {
    email: { required, email },
    password: { required }
  },
  signup: {
    email: { required, email },
    firstName: { required, maxLength: maxLength(40) },
    lastName: { required, maxLength: maxLength(40) }
  }
}
```

then when you submit one of the forms, let's say the login, you can just check if only it is invalid without worrying about the sign up form validation and vise versa.

```
  if (this.$v.login.$invalid) {
    this.errorMessage = "invalid login form";
  } else {
    this.loginByPassword();
  }
}
```